# How I can get preprocessed c++ code in Visual Studio Extention project?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I make Visual Studio Extension for C++. I can get source code from file using DTE.ActiveDocument, but it can contain elements like macros that will be replaced after preprocess to the another code. I tried to use DTE.CodeElements, but it also return code elements before proprocess.

Comment: Have a look at the [DevUtils](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=trass3r.trass3rdevutils) extension.